# read a content from a file and store it in database tables in ruby

Tags: ruby, psql

I am having some content in file. I already read the specific needed content and store it in one array and variables

Now i need to pass those value of the array and variable to the created table in database

Please help me to do this.

```
con = PG.connect :dbname => 'user1', :user => 'user1'
puts con.server_version
con.exec "SELECT exists(select schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name = 'testing');"
con.exec "set search_path TO testing;"
con.exec "create table table1(name varchar());"
```

Now lets say i am having the below value,

```
a="someone"
```

How do i insert that value to the table. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, check out this documentation page, it has examples too: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-insert.html

Comment: If it's possible to use ActiveRecord (with or without Rails) in your project, that may make things a lot easier for you.

Comment: I have answered my question. Please refer

Answer (score 0):

We have to parse the value like this,

```
con.exec "insert into xox values('#{a}');"
```